# Trying to implement a form with php/ajax without success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to implement a form based on a tutorial found on the internet. Unfortunately I can't get it working. When I click on "Send" the page reloads and that's it.
Any idea what the issue is? Many thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block-right">  <h1>Formulaire de contact</h1>
            <!-- CONTACT FORM-->
            <div class="contact-form">


                <form id="contact" method="post" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="">
                        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="">
                    </div>

                    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

                    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="submit">

  <p class="success" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>
  <p class="error" style="display:none">E-mail must be valid and message must be longer than 100 characters.</p>
                </form>
            </div><!-- /.contact-form -->
</div>  <!-- End DIV block-right -->
```

**JS:**

```
    // Contact Form
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#contact").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var message = $("#message").val();
      var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
      function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
      };

      if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 100) && (name.length > 1)){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../sendmessage.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
          $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        });
      } else{
        $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
      }

      return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //send email
  mail( "xyz@gmail.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] );

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you imported jquery library in the HTML part?

Comment: Any error in console? Is submit event fired? Are you waiting DOM ready handler or setting handler after #contact form being accessible? Are all your IDs unique on context page?

Comment: Are you missing DOM ready and haven't actually selected `#contact`? The preventDefault looks good otherwise.

Comment: FYI, your `dataString` var is trying to use a `text` variable which does not exist. Maybe you mean `message`.

Comment: I know this is code you are still developing, but just a heads up: Your code has a [Mail Header Injection Attack(http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/email-injection/) weakness.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Sébastien, I fixed the dataString. Looking at the console I have this error message: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#contact")')"

Comment: Can you confirm that you have included jQuery on your page? And have you tried what @KhanhTO has suggested in his answer?

Comment: Yes confirmed. Could it be due to the fact that I have no #contact set in my CSS stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to wrap your code inside `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#contact").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     //Your code.

     return false;
  });
});
```

Or use delegated event:

```
$(document).on("submit","#contact",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

         //Your code.

      return false;
 });
```

**Update:**
If you use `.noConflict();` to relinquish control of `$`. You could try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#contact").submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         //Your code.

         return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Khan. I updated my code accordingly. Looking at the console I have this error message: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#contact")')"

Comment: @Greg: it could be that jquery is not included and `$` is undefined.

Comment: @Greg: also ensure that there is no other code on your page overwriting the `$` (example: `prototype.js` also uses `$`)

Comment: @Greg: I see that you use `tpj.noConflict();` to relinquish control of `$`

Comment: @Greg: you could simply try `jQuery("#contact")`

Comment: @Greg: `jQuery` and `$` refer to the same jquery function in memory when jquery library is loaded, but after you use `.noConflict();`, `$` is not valid anymore. Fortunately, we still have the `jQuery` variable to use

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed the noconflict and it is now working!